# Netbeans and PhpDocumentor

Tags: windows, user-interface, netbeans, phpdoc

I have downloaded Netbeans 7.0 beta as I wanted to give the PhpDoc functionality a bash, but can't get it to work.
I seem to be falling over on the configuration options for PhpDoc in netbeans. It is asking for the script location,
[image]

but whatever I enter I get the error;

```
** ERROR *****************************************************************
* Sorry, can't find the php.exe file.
* You must edit this file to point to your php.exe (CLI version!)
*    [Currently set to C:\usr\local\php\cli\php.exe]
* 
* NOTE: In PHP 4.2.x the PHP-CLI used to be named php-cli.exe. 
*       PHP 4.3.x renamed it php.exe but stores it in a subdir 
*       called /cli/php.exe
*       E.g. for PHP 4.2 C:\phpdev\php-4.2-Win32\php-cli.exe
*            for PHP 4.3 C:\phpdev\php-4.3-Win32\cli\php.exe
**************************************************************************
Press any key to continue . . .
```

The set-up is Netbeans and xampp running on a windows machine.

Any and all help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That error indicates that the php.exe executable file is not in your Windows "PATH", and as such, when Windows tries to run the phpdoc script, it doesn't know how.  Fortunately, the phpdoc script itself checks for this condition and explains it to you, in the error text you posted.  Otherwise, the Windows error would have been much more generic and probably unhelpful.

You need to determine where your php.exe file is located.  Then, edit the phpdoc.bat script file itself to hardcode the absolute path.  Look for the line near the beginning that SETs the phpCli value.  That is where you should place the absolute path to your php.exe file.

As an aside, I would suggest that your "PhpDoc script" setting in NetBeans should explicitly call the phpdoc.bat script rather than just "phpdoc", e.g. D:\xampp\php\phpdoc.bat, since both files actually exist.  I know that Windows will typically look for "foo.bat" if you tell it to execute "foo" when foo doesn't exist and foo.bat does exist, but since phpdoc and phpdoc.bat both exist, ... I think that Windows trying to run phpdoc directly rather than phpdoc.bat will give you trouble.

Further, I see that you have the phpdoc.bat file itself listed as the first "argument" to the phpdoc script.  That will probably cause you some grief once you get past the "can't find php.exe" error.  You should remove that... the only arguments you should give after naming the script itself are the valid arguments that phpDocumentor expects, particularly the ones it *requires* -- -o for output template, -t for where to write the doc files, -d or -f  to tell it where the PHP code is that you want documented.

Comment: Thanks, you have got me further. I have set the include in phpdoc.bat to "D:\xampp\php\php.exe" and the NB setting to "D:\xampp\htdocs\PhpDocumentor\phpdoc.bat -o HTML:frames:earthli", now I get an error of "Could not open input file: phpdoc".

Comment: Hmmm, you mean phpdoc.bat wasn't in the D:\xampp\php directory?  If that's where "phpdoc" is, I would have expected "phpdoc.bat" to also be there.  If you do see it there, change your NB pathing and try again.  I think that PHP's default include_path contains ".", which would mean that running "phpdoc.bat" from D:\xampp\php would then be successful in seeing "phpdoc" there too.

Comment: to install phpdocumentor I just dumped all the files in a directory under the htdocs of my xampp install (I have done it like this before on a web server). The php.exe file is the one of the xampp install is in "D:\xampp\php" and the phpdoc.bat of phpdocumentor is in "D:\xampp\htdocs\PhpDocumentor". Have I installed phpdocumentor incorrectly?

Comment: In order to phpDocumentor to run successfully from just anywhere you put the files, your PHP include_path will need to be updated to include whatever directory you put the PhpDocumentor folder in, e.g. D:\xampp\htdocs.  You should check your php.ini file to see how the include_path is set.

Answer (score 3):

for my case, in the version 2:
i changed the last line in phpdoc.bat:

```
"%PHPBIN%" "%PHP_PERAR_BIN_DIR%\phpdoc.php" %*
```

to

```
"%PHPBIN%" "phpdoc.php" %*
```

`%PHP_PERAR_BIN_DIR%` in this case is empty & the backslash makes an error finding the phpdoc.php file

Answer (score 2):

I finally figured out an easy way to use phpdoc in Netbeans Windows!

Pear? Drop it. There's way too many problems.

1. Download it directly - http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpdocu/files/
2. Download the tar file, not the zip. The zip is bugged and will output 2 letter extensions instead of 3 (ie, .cs instead of .css) (as of 1.4.3)
3. Unzip it anywhere you want
4. Open up the phpdoc.bat file, and make 2 changes
5. a) Change the phpcli path
6. b) Add in code to navigate to the directory.

So for example, I put my phpdocumentor folder in d:\programs\xampp\php\phpdoc. Modifying the phpdoc.bat file:

```
    SET phpCli=d:\programs\xampp\php\php.exe
    d:
    cd d:\programs\xampp\php\phpdoc
```

Then in Netbeans, you put this for the phpdoc script:

```
    D:\programs\xampp\php\phpdoc\phpdoc.bat -o HTML:frames:earthli
```

Note that when you set the target (right click on project -> properties -> phpdoc), you will need to manually change the backslashes to forward slashes.

- Correct - D:/programs/xampp/htdocs/project/phpdoc
- Incorrect - D:\programs\xampp\htdocs\project\phpdoc (this will be generated when you use the browse button)

Good luck!

PS. Note that you can also run the phpdoc batch file directly from dos. You don't need to do it through netbeans.

```
    d:\programs\xampp\php\phpdoc\phpdoc.bat -d D:\programs\xampp\htdocs\project -t D:\programs\xampp\htdocs\project\phpdoc -o HTML:frames:phpedit
```

Comment: The Zip file seems okay now, however I only ever got it working from the commandline